# How to reduce cpu load on mpd to m3u8 restreaming

Tags: ffmpeg, restrictions, hls

I have 100% CPU load on restreaming. Is there any solution to reduce it?

```
[program:channel]
autorestart=true
command=/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -headers 'Referer: https://example.com/' -i https://stream.webm.mpd -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_flags append_list+delete_segments -hls_list_size 6 -hls_segment_filename '/etc/nginx/hls/channel/file%%03d.ts' /etc/nginx/hls/channel/playlist.m3u8
linux
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode.

Normal `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -re -headers 'Referer: https://example.com/' -i https://stream.webm.mpd -c copy -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_flags append_list+delete_segments -hls_list_size 6 -hls_segment_filename '/etc/nginx/hls/channel/file%03d.ts' /etc/nginx/hls/channel/playlist.m3u8
```

Modified for supervisor:

```
[program:channel]
autorestart=true
command=/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -re -headers 'Referer: https://example.com/' -i https://stream.webm.mpd -c copy -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_flags append_list+delete_segments -hls_list_size 6 -hls_segment_filename '/etc/nginx/hls/channel/file%%03d.ts' /etc/nginx/hls/channel/playlist.m3u8
```

If stream copy is not an option and you must re-encode then manually use the `-threads` option or use the Linux `nice` command, or whatever is the equivalent for your currently unknown OS, but performance may suffer.

Comment: I get following error:

Comment: error: <class 'xmlrpclib.Fault'>, <Fault 92: 'CANT_REREAD: Format string "/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -re -headers \'Referer: https://.peer-stream.com/\' -i https://h5p2p.pe.de.webm.mpd -c copy -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_flags append_list+delete_segments -hls_list_size 6 -hls_segment_filename \'/etc/nginx/hls/channel/file%03d.ts\' /etc/nginx/hls/channel/playlist.m3u8" for \'program:dmax.command\' is badly formatted: %d format: a number is required, not dict in section \'program:dmax\' (file: \'/etc/supervisor/conf.d/restream.conf\')'>:

Comment: @Marhul88 That's not an error from ffmpeg. I provided a plain ffmpeg command. You have to escape the `%` so it works in whatever script/code/language you are using (which I do not know because you didn't mention it).

Comment: It is ubuntu 18, nginx + rtmp restreaming.

Comment: that cause 100% CPu load:  [program:channel]
autorestart=true
command=/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -headers 'Referer: https://example.com/' -i https://example.com/chunks/kabel_e_hq.webm.mpd -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_flags append_list+delete_segments -hls_list_size 6 -hls_segment_filename '/etc/nginx/hls/channel/file%%03d.ts' /etc/nginx/hls/channel/playlist.m3u8

Comment: @Marhul88 *"that cause 100% CPu load"* That's not using `-c copy` like in my answer. Doesn't look much different than your command in your question. *"It is nginx + rtmp restreaming"*. You asked how to reduce CPU load in ffmpeg, so that's what I am giving answer to do. Your nginx syntax problems are a completely separate issue and have nothing to so with the CPU issue.

Comment: U asked what system i use. Should i remove just a "-c copy"

Comment: @Marhul88 You have to use the command I gave you, but you have to provide the proper input file name and you may have to adjust the syntax so it works in `restream.conf`.

Comment: exact, it is "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/restream.conf". i use your command exactly so as u wrote. But it returnes my error

Comment: @Marhul88 I answered your question on how to reduce CPU load using ffmpeg. But now you are changing to question to something completely different: "how to get ffmpeg command to work in supervisor?". You have to modify the command so it works in `restream.conf`. That means you may have to escape the `%`. I am not familiar with supervisor, but I'm guessing you need to use `file%%03d.ts` instead of `file%03d.ts`. If that doesn't help you can make a new question to address this syntax issue, "how to get ffmpeg command to work in supervisor?"

Comment: @Marhul88 I updated the answer and escaped the `%` for you so you can blindly copy and paste for rote usage.